# The type or namespace name CustomerBL does not exist in the namespace 'BusinessLayer' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a windows application c# (.net 2.0) which consist of Interface layer,business layer and data layer
each layer tied with  each other by reference to communicate send receive data.
Now the problem, when ever any data type or spelling mistake error happens  in business layer, the reference of business layer disappearing in data layer. then the project totally gone and throwing uncountable errors such as on the title.To run the project again ,I have to rebuild all the layer again which consumes lot of time.

Does anybody have any solution to avoid the DLL loosing?

Thanks.

Comment: Are these projects all part of the same solution? Are you using Project references or simply pointing to the generated DLLs? If all of your projects are in the same solution you can "Build All" or "Rebuild All", and it's almost no work at all.

Comment: Yes...all projects are part of the same solution.I am using Project reference.I did the rebuild solution and got the same error msg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the spelling error in your business layer causes auto-compile to totally fail and reject the reference to it as a valid assembly. Try getting the business layer to a state where it will compile and compile it.

**EDIT-START**

I'm assuming here that you have a multiple project solution with 3 projects: data, business and interface. I'm also assuming that your business layer is referenced by your data layer *"the reference of business layer disappearing in data layer"*. (This is strange as standard architecture would have a business layer referencing the data layer, not the other way around).

Try to compile to the business project. If you cannot compile without errors, fix any errors in the business project until you can compile the business project without errors. Don't worry about any errors in the other projects until you can get the business project error free.

**EDIT-END**

This may give the auto-compile something to fall back on in the case of the auto-compile failing.

Comment: //Try getting the business layer to a state where it will compile and compile it.// Can you give some more info on this.